# Find Length of Object and then map over it Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a array of data objects, I want to map over them and then use the result in an if statement to flatten:

```
outsideData = {
id: 1,
city: 'London'
data: [
{ 
name: 'Test 1', 
age: 15,
value: 20
},
{
name: 'Test 2',
age: 20, 
value: 26
},
{
name: 'Test 3',
age: 31,
value: 45
},
{
name: 'Test 4',
age: 45,
value: 79
}]

}
```

And a have another object I want to add if the length is something

```
const address = {
   value: 2
}
```

```
const city = {
   value: 10
}
```

Now I want to check if the length of the data array

```
const myData = outsideData.data
```

If the length of the data is less than 3 add this object if greater than three had this object

```
if (outsideData.data.length <= 3) {
  .map((d) => {
     return [
       {
          name: d,
          age: true
         },
       address
  ]

}).flat(1)
} else {
.map((name) => {
     return [
       {
          name: d,
          age: true
         },
       city
  ]
}
}
```

Something like this, how can I achieve mapping if it has a length that a specific size.

Thank you,

Comment: `data` has no key of `slices`.  I'm very confused by this question.

Comment: define length in object. do you mean... the count of keys in object? Object.keys(data[i]).length is what you are looking for.... right?

Comment: Fixed it. Yes, basically I wanted to find the length of the data...right now there are 4 objects in the array. Now I want to add another object IF the object is greater than 3 (which it is). What about if it's less than three than I want to add another object. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

to get the count of properties in an object. you can use Object.keys(); to get an array from an object... which has a length property. (i don't think keys guarantees order being preserved - but that's not relevant to your question.

```
const newData = data.map(d=>{
    if(Object.keys(d).length <= 3){
        return {...d, address}; //98% sure on this syntax;
    }else{return d;}
});
```

even more concisely

```
const newData = data.map(d=>Object.keys(d).length <= 3 ?{...d, address}:d);
```

Comment: Probably want a copy of address so each item has it's own

Comment: ^ agreed - or make it in the map as needed? is it a placeholder, or is it from an array? implementation remains unclear. but crux - getting length from an object. is Object.keys(objectInQuestion)

Comment: aye - details are unclear, but it isn't about map, or correctly mapping the object. question was just about getting length from an object.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm confusing myself lol. If the data length is greater than 3 had address, if it's less than 3 add address2. That's the simplest way I can think of it.

Comment: so length is just object property count, cool. address is just a placeholder then? (in that case -yes, for sure make a new copy for each address, lest all address2's point to the same object. and is it an object you want to append, or the key=>value pair added to the object?

Comment: Okay I have fixed it....I thought about it wrong. It's an object with a array of objects.

Comment: @altruios Thank you for your help....I'm trying to describe it but my brain is scrambled lol. It's an object of an array of objects that I'm mapping through if the length is a certain number or if it's another number and added the other objects to them to flatten. Please tell me if that is much more clearer?

Comment: so do you want the object at the end to be 
{name: 'Test 1', 
age: 15,
value: 20
address: ""}


or...


[{name: 'Test 1', 
age: 15,
value: 20},address]

if it is the former... flatten is not at all what you need.
either a map with a return. or you could simply modify in place with a forEach loop. data.forEach(x=>Object.keys(x).length<=3?x.address = "":null)

Comment: Thank you soo much! I figured it out! Basically I forgot that I can map around the data and then inside of that have my conditional statements and then flat the result. It was a doozy! I will make sure future question details are much much clearer.